# Unable to access url without index.php in CodeIgniter project

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm trying to setup the CodeIgniter project on local.
For example : http://fit.now/index.php/Admin/dashboard
If I try to access other url instead of main url http://fit.now.
then It return 404.
**my .htaccess file code**

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**route.php file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index';
$route['logout'] = 'login/logout';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**httpd-vhost.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Admin/"
    ServerName fitbit.now
</VirtualHost>
```

local host file
[image]

**my config.php file**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://fitbit.now/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
//$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my htdocs, you can try it in your project:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```